# printf - raw string literal with format macro of fixed width integer types

Tags: c++, printf, string-literals

How do I use raw string literal `R` with format macro of fixed width integer types?

For example

```
std::int64_t num = INT64_MAX;
std::printf(R"("name":"%s", "number":"%")" PRId64, "david", num); // wrong syntax
```

The output should be

```
"name":"david", "number":"9223372036854775807"
```

Use of escape sequences instead of `R` is not permitted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, you should check your current format string with `puts()`.

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <cinttypes>

int main(void) {
    std::puts(R"("name":"%s", "number":"%")" PRId64);
    return 0;
}
```

[Result](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wyP5RdPXMFiESZWn):

```
"name":"%s", "number":"%"ld
```

Now you see the errors:

- You have an extra `"` between `%` and `ld`.
- `"` is missing after `ld`.

Based on this, fix the format string:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <cinttypes>

int main(void) {
    std::int64_t num = INT64_MAX;
    std::printf(R"("name":"%s", "number":"%)" PRId64 R"(")", "david", num);
    return 0;
}
```

[Result](https://wandbox.org/permlink/NoiMEwJFgwIVHP08):

```
"name":"david", "number":"9223372036854775807"
```

Comment: Smart work, @MikeCAT.

Answer (score 0):

[@MikeCAT's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72914008/65863) shows how to do this with string literal concatenation at compile-time.

Another option would be to create the format string at runtime instead, eg:

```
char fmt[36] = {};
std::sprintf(fmt, R"("name":"%%s", "number":"%%%s")", PRId64);
std::printf(fmt, "david", num);
```

Or:

```
std::string fmt = R"("name":"%s", "number":"%)" + std::string(PRId64) + R"(")";
std::printf(fmt.c_str(), "david", num);
```

Though, I would not rely on using `PRId64` at all, I would let C++ format the `num` for me, eg:

```
std::cout << R"("name":)" << std::quoted("david") << R"(, "number":)" << std::quoted(std::to_string(num));
```

Or, in C++20 (or using the [{fmt}](https://fmt.dev/latest/index.html) library):

```
std::cout << std::format(R"("name":"{}", "number":"{}")", "david", num);
```